# odoo 10 can't create a submenu in sale module

Tags: menu, odoo

I'm learning odoo 10 development with odooclass and I am blocked at the submenu creation step. Here my piece of code from the addon views.xml:

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="dmsapp.action_window_vehicles" >
        <field name="name">Vehicles</field>
        <field name="res_model">dmsapp.vehicle</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="Vehicles" id="dmsapp.menu_vehicles" parent="sales_team.menu_sales"
        action="dmsapp.action_window_vehicles"/>
```

The menu never appears but I can see it in the list of all sales menu  items (developper>parameters>UI>menu) near product, customers, quotation...

I had rerun odoo, refresh web browser, clear cach and cookies, try to put groups acess, change sequence but the menu never appears.
I am logged as Administrator.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably solves odoo caching problem: update your module/app. If it doesn't work uninstall and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

try change this `parent="sales_team.menu_sales"`

into this

```
parent="sales_team.menu_base_partner"
```

hope this help

Comment: I retry on my VM snapshot with your code and my submenu become a first level menu from sale module. Then when I come back to sales_team.menu_sales it appears in sale submenu. I don't understand why it don't work at the first shot...

Comment: have you tried upgrading your addons by click upgrade button in apps>youraddonsname ? FYI restarting odoo-service IS NOT upgrading the XML, only the python files. you must click that button after change the XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I remove Shan Abdiel and vijay suggestions, rerun and it appears now. It's really a mystery. Does odoo-bin keep a sort of cache of generated html or other trick tike that? Is there a way to fully clear it?
Is it possible that this problem come with liclipse ? I notice that I remove all terminal launches before it worked. But I already did that yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

Give access right of showing menu of Sales Team from **res_users**  and rerun again.

Comment: I don't know what is res_users and how to do that.  Do you speak about groups tag in view.xml?

Comment: No, frist tell me which version of odoo are you using then I'll explain you.

Comment: the last one: odoo 10

Comment: First of all you need to activate developer mode. For that you can follow steps of this link: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-see-the-and-activate-the-developer-mode-in-odoo-version-10-109530

After activating dev mode you have been redirected to main menu automatically. From that again you have to go to **Settings >> Users**. Here you have to choose your relevant user.(Mostly it is **Administrator
**)  after choosing user from **Access Right** page find **Technical Settings** in that check all checkboxes and refresh page. Then check your submenu.

Comment: this doesn't do anything. Probably no link between these check box and my submenu sale item